# Drop Down in every rows of a Rally Table

Tags: rally

May I know if it's possible to have a drop down box in every row in the Rally Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is.  Check out this example here (scroll down to Displaying Components in Cells):
http://developer.rallydev.com/help/tables

If you'd like to also make an update to the data when the value of the dropdown changes you'll want to wire up a listener to the onChange event and then use RallyDataSource's update method to change the data in Rally.